# Window titles disappear when setting scale to 0.875 on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, window

When I set **Scale for window and title bars** to 0.875 in **System Settings -> Screen Display**, the window title text disappears in all windows. They appear fine at any other scale, but to my eye, 0.875 is the perfect scale, which is annoying...

How can I fix this so the window titles appear?

Answer (score 2):

Window titles also disappear when setting scale to any position except 1 on Ubuntu 16.04 for me.

I use scaling 1.25:

[image: screenshot]

In Unity Tweak Tool, if I set the default font for windows title to **Ubuntu 11**, text in all window titles disappears.

If i set **Ubuntu Regular 11** titles on some windows exist and on some do not exist

I tried to use many fonts and sizes and finally with **DejaVu Sans Mono Bold 10** all windows titles show normally

[image: screenshot]

So open a couple of different windows and try to find a font that works for you in Unity Tweak Tool.